# Showing an element If correct option is Selected with Angular 4 and Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am fairly new to the Angular world and have a requirement to fulfill. I have a dropdown lost populated with values from the TS component, Four values, with the last being Other. What I would like to see happen, is when the option for Other is selected within the dropdown I would like to show an input element for that option only. I am using Angular Material and have been struggling with this most of the afternoon.

Here is my code below

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select placeholder="Company Type" formControlName="companyType"  #companyType required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let companyType of companyTypes" [value]="companyType">
                  {{ companyType }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>

      <div ng-show="md-selected-text ==='Other'" class="col-md-8">
           <mat-form-field>
               <input matInput placeholder="Explain">
            </mat-form-field>                
      </div>
</div>
```

And here is the Typescript code for the component

```
export class HealthPlanComponent implements OnInit {
companyTypes = ['Health Insurance Company/HMO', 'Self-Insured Employee 
               Health Plan', 'Self-Insured Health & Welfare Fund', 'Other'];
}

submitTppClaim(): void {
    this.submitted = true;
    newClaim.companyType = this.consumerClaim.get('companyType').value;
      .subscribe(claim => {
      this.submitted = false;
      this.submittedClaim = claim;
      this.notSubmitted = false;
    });
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the following:

*ngIf="yourFormName.get('companyType').value === 'Other'"

Comment: Wow, thank you @Alexandr2134, this helped and it working as should, been trying to figure this out most of the afternoon.